# Closing a dynamically loaded jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 web that opens a jquery dialog with the content of a partial view.

```
  div.load(baseUrl + 'Home/AssignWarehouse?warehouseId=' + warehouseId + '&countryId=' + countryId).dialog(
        {
            width: 400,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            close: function (even, ui) {
                refreshMatrix(warehouseId, countryId);
            }
        }
    );
```

The view that loads is a simple list of checkboxes and a Save-button just added to the form.

The partial view. I havn't added any scripts yet.

```
@model AjaxConcept2.Controllers.AssignWarehouseModel

<div style="width:49%; display: inline-block">

    <h3>Country</h3>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CountryText)

</div>

<div style="width:49%; display: inline-block;">


    <h3>Warehouse</h3>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WarehouseText)

</div>

<div style="margin-top: 20px;">

    <input type="checkbox"/> Option A<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"/> Option B<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"/> Option C

</div>

<input type="button" value="Save">
```

My question is, can I close the dialog from that Save-button in a simple way? I want to run script that is defined in the partial view and then close the dialog. I'm not well versed in jquery and jquery.ui. :)

The Save button is in the partial view, loaded dynamically and the click on it is the trigger.

Edit:

Do I need to keep all javascripts global and track input-fields with unique id's or classes? What I was hoping for was to run scripts from the partial view.

// Johan

Comment: where is the save button handler

Comment: Would it be possible to use the ``buttons`` attribute for your dialog options? You should look into it in case they don't necessarily need to be inside your loaded content. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: I still don't see a save button in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `close` method to close any dialog.

```
// If your div is still known or available
div.dialog('close');

// Any element which is a dialog
$('.element').dialog('close');
```

Also, see the [jQuery UI API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close).

You can delegate the save button's event to `document`. Let's assume that your save button has the class `btn-save`. You can do the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-save', function () {
    $('.my-dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

For more on event delegation, [check this page in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. User specifically asked for clarification on how to do this with the save button specified inside his dynamically loaded partial view.

Comment: Removed the downvote, though I'm not sure this would work with dynamically-loaded content.

Comment: That's why we have event delegation. By delegating the event handler to `document`, you can capture the events even from dynamically added elements.